# .htaccess Rewrite with multiple domains?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm running an oxwall site with 3 languages and 3 domains and want to connect each domain with correct language. Each language is reached by a certain url.

Danish language example: mydomain.com?language_id=31

mydomain.dk is redirected to mydomain.com by domain provider

How can i get the danish visitor to see mydomain.dk in address bar?
The danish language works but the domain is .com in address bar.

I got this in my .htacess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ ?language_id=30 [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.dk
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ ?language_id=31 [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.fi
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ ?language_id=32 [NC,L]
```

Comment: You said `mydomain.dk is redirected to mydomain.com by domain provider`. As long as that's happening you won't be able to show mydomain.dk in the address bar. You need to remove that redirect among other things.

Comment: @PanamaJack okey, after i do that can i achieve this by only working with .htacess or do need some kind of php script also?